# Saving a csv file from Shiny app inputs in the server storage

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a table in Shiny from different inputs and save it in the server as a file in this location `/dest/folder/`. Here is what I am working on. The saving part is not working. Anyone here to help me solve the problem?

```
library(shiny)
    
ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Choices"),
      sidebarPanel(
        
        textInput(inputId = "name",
                  label = "Name",
                  value = "Name"),
        
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "choices",
                           label = "Choice",
                           c("Beer" = "beer",
                             "Vodka" = "vodka",
                             "Whisky" = "whisky")),
        
        actionButton("button", "Build file"),
        downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
        ),
        mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Data", tableOutput(outputId = "table")))))

    server <- function(input, output){
    
      loc <- "/dest/folder/"
      dataandtime <- Sys.time()
      
      rv <- reactiveValues(
        df = data.frame(
          Name = character(),
          Choices = character()
        )
      )
      
      observeEvent(input$button, {
        df <- data.frame(
          Name = input$name,
          Choices = input$choices
        )
        
        output$table <-renderTable({
          df})
        
        output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
          filename = function() {
            paste0(dateandtime, ".csv", sep = "")
          },
          content = function(file) {
            write.csv(df, filename)
            file.copy(inFile$datapath, file.path(loc, paste0(dataandtime, "_", "NAME", ".csv")))
          }
        )   
      }
      )
    }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```